# how to use active storage variant method to crop picture to circle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimagick, rails-activestorage

I have found a way to do it using Minimagick, but I don't know how to use active
storage's variant method to do so. As it will support with lazy feature, I think it might be better.

```
MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |cvrt|
  cvrt.size '300x300'
  cvrt << 'xc:transparent'
  cvrt.fill 'image.png'
  cvrt.draw "circle 240,90 290,90"
  cvrt.crop '100x100+190+40'
  cvrt.repage.+
  cvrt << 'circle.png'
end
```

Comment: Can you convert that to a `mogrify` command line? Or better (IMHO), use the variant to scale and crop the image but leave the circle part to CSS.

Comment: Actually, not using CSS is mainly because of the need to render an avatar in google map, which does not support CSS elegantly.